# Flutter How put a widget inside an Image

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to incorporate a widget inside my image. But the problem is that all the ways that I found dont have a child method so I can't put a widget in there.
The last thing that I tried was to use BoxDecoration inside a Container and use child for the widget that I want to display inside. But the size of the container don't match with this image I don't know why. Anyone have an idea ?

my code:

[image]

Comment: Please your code shouldn't be a screenshot. Copy paste instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `fit`, like this:

```
Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,//<--- add this
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/test.jpeg'),
                )),
            child: ...
          ),
```

result before:

[image]

result after:

[image]

Comment: Thank you I tried and it works very well with BoxFit.fill

Comment: glad to here that, If it was helpful please up vote it so other people find it easier. @Koda

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Row()` with `Positioned()` and play around with `alignment`

Answer (score 0):

the `Stack` widget is what you need, simply it just considers its children as layers :

```
Stack(
children= <Widget>[
YourImageWidget(),
AnotherWidget(),
]
)
```

this will put one over the other widget
to control the position of your widget, Wrap it with the `Positioned` widget and set top, left, bottom, and right properties.
or wrap with the `Align` widget and set alignment property , example :

```
 Stack(
children= <Widget>[
YourImageWidget(),
Positioned(
bottom: 0,
left: 15
child: AnotherWidget(),
)
]
)
```